# C# - Event when closing WebBrowser

Tags: c#, .net, webbrowser-control, eventhandler

I have a .NET Control with an WebBrowser in it.
This Control is used in my Application in a Form.

So if I close this Form or the whole Application or if I do anything that my WebBrowser is going to be closed I need to fire an event.

Ive tried it like this, but the if function does not works in the way I want it:

```
private void webBrowser1_VisibleChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!webBrowser1.Visible)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Hi");
        }
    }
```

Any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

this code for after you closed the form....

```
       private void webBrowser1_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
            MessageBox.Show("WebBrowser Closed");
    }
```

this code for asking permission to do something while closing...

```
   private void frmReader_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
            MessageBox.Show("Are you sure want to close the WebBrowser?");
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, but i need to handle this event inside the Control with the WebBrowser, not in the Form which contains this control... Problem is, that this control is already used by 100 Forms.

Comment: try this..........private void webBrowser1_VisibleChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   MessageBox.Show("Visible change event raised!!!");
}

Comment: private void webBrowser1_VisibleChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {             if (!WebBrowser1.Visible)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("true");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("false");
            }}

Answer (score 0):

Only the form knows when it's being closed. A way to accomplish this is to have your control find its containing form using `Control.FindForm()`, register handlers for the form's closing events (e.g. during initialization), and raise new events from the control.